# How to arrange Windows 7 task bar icons in 2 rows?

Tags: windows-7, taskbar

I have my windows 7 task bar set to 2 rows.  I would like to arrange the items I have pined to the taksbar in 2 rows without waiting for them to be wrapped.

Is this possible in Windows 7?  If so how do you do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. Having multiple rows is only for overflow. And you can only re-order items, not re-position them arbitrarily into space that isn't occupied yet by the taskbar buttons.<sup>1</sup>

<sup>1</sup> Educated guess, not knowledge. However, [features don't exist by default, they have to be implemented by someone](http://blogs.technet.com/seanearp/archive/2007/04/12/why-doesn-t-this-feature-exist.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I know in XP and Vista, you could unlock the taskbar and drag it up, but I'm not sure if this works with 7.

Comment: You can do that, and I have done that.  But what I want to do is arrange the icons in 2 rows.